# Is it possible to use a fluorometer such as Qubit or Denovix DS-11 FX to detect DNA integrity/fragmentation?

Tags: dna-damage

I remember someone saying that the Thermo Fisher Qubit can be used to assess DNA integrity, is this true?

Our lab recently acquired a different fluorometer, the Denovix DS-11 FX. I'm wondering if it can be used to detect DNA integrity. I couldn't find any info about it in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

In general, methods like Qubit rely on specific interactions between a fluorescent dye and the target molecules, be they dsDNA, ssDNA, RNA, or whatever. These are sensitive to the overall *amounts* of targets, not their size distributions (within reason, of course). For DNA, you will need to use an electrophoretic method like a Bioanalyzer or an agarose gel to quantify integrity.

Comment: The Qubit has an RNA integrity kit. They call it RNA IQ which works off binding of two different molecules. I haven't used it, so can't say if it is comparable to bioanalyzer, but they claim it is as good as electrophoresis (presumably visual inspection for integrity on this one). Bioanalyzer is the gold standard for RNA AFAIK, don't know about DNA.

Comment: There isn't an equivalent fluorescent method for DNA. Bioanalyzer orTapestation is the way to go.